# MySQL join tables and show values excluding specific user_id

Tags: mysql

**Details:**

**MySQL tables**

```
create table request (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    date_requested timestamp,
    user_id int
);


create table verify (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    user_id int,
    request_id int,
    created timestamp
);
```

**Values**

Request Table

```
ID     DATE REQUESTED    USER ID
1          2020..           1
2          2020..           3
```

Verify Table

```
ID    USER_ID    REQUEST_ID     CREATED
1       2            1            2020...
```

**Problem:**

I have this query below:

```
select * from request join verify on request.id = verify.request_id where verify.user_id !=2;
```

This returns me nothing. Why is it not showing the 2nd record from `request` table?

My goal is simply return all values from `request` tables based on this:

- If `record.id` is in `verify` table then check if `verify` table has `user_id` of 2
- If it does, then do not show that `request` record
- If there are no `record.id` in `verify` table at all
- Then show them

Comment: try a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join of the tables and filter out the matching rows:

```
select r.* 
from request r left join verify v
on r.id = v.request_id and v.user_id =2
where v.request_id is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7HpQHAfkKzp21d9t76uRP/2).
Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select r.* 
from request r 
where not exists (
  select 1 from verify v
  where r.id = v.request_id and v.user_id =2
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7HpQHAfkKzp21d9t76uRP/5).
Results:

```
| id  | date_requested      | user_id |
| --- | ------------------- | ------- |
| 2   | 2020-04-08 00:00:00 | 3       |
```

Comment: @lpemvonm check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7HpQHAfkKzp21d9t76uRP/0 Isn't this that you want?